# sprintf adds minus sign to zero after rounding

Tags: r, printf, rounding, negative-number

Let's do some rounding

```
> round(-0.001, 2)
[1] 0
```

I receive zero.

Now in combination with sprintf

```
> sprintf("%f", round(-0.001,2))
[1] "-0.000000"
```

Why is there a minus sign? I expected `0.000000`.

```
$R --version
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
```

Comment: If you don't like the behaviour, just add nothing: `sprintf("%f", round(-0.001,2) + 0)`.

Comment: Great! This is a simple solution to this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the nature of floating point numbers (IEEE 754), there is a `-0` defined. See [-0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%920).